# Making a list into this format

Tags: python-3.x, formatting

I'm having a lot of trouble with this transformation. How do I make a function to take a list and print it out into a format like the one below the list? This is in python 3.3 by the way.

```
[[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']]
```

It's supposed to look like a 7x6 connect 4 game board:

```
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  
.  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  R  .  .  .  .
.  .  Y  R  .  .  .
.  R  R  Y  .  Y  .
```

Comment: What language is this? Python?

Answer (score 0):

Since this looks like python, you're getting a python answer:

```
arr = [[1,2],[3,4]]
for rows in arr:
    rowString = ""
    for value in rows:
        rowString = rowString + str(value)
    print(rowString)
```

Comment: can this be answered in a more simpler form?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop and `join` to do this:

```
for row in board:
    print ' '.join(cell for cell in cells if cell != ' ' else '.')
```

Comment: haha is there a even more simpler form to write this we haven't done list comprehension yet

Comment: `print_board_game(board)`? What are you looking for?

Comment: Maybe like two for loops with str and indices. We haven't learned arrays or list comprehension yet. I'm in a beginner python course

Comment: Well I don't think anything is wrong with it, it's just not at my level  heh. I tried it out on the shell but it said cell does not exist. Thanks for helping me out.